# iOS11 + Webview - Images in scrolling div disappear, don't come back

Tags: html, css, cordova, webview, ios11

This issue doesn't occur in iOS9 or iOS10.

The webview is part of an app made using Cordova.

An element has a series of tiles with images and titles in them, for selecting media to view.

The elements have `position: relative` but no values for any side.
They have a child with `position: absolute`, this is the title of the media content.
The elements have a unique background image each, with the following accompanying css:

`background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;`

When the content is scrolled, there is frequently an issue where the elements are derendered, including the text, but when they should scroll back into view, they don't reappear. You can actually still click where an item should be rendered, and go the the correct page.

This is pretty bad because a full screen height of content appears blank in many situations.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add little animation (2pxX2px) on the page where content disappears. it will refresh view render and you will see all content. Not best solution, but it works

Comment: I tried every "good" way, but this was the right direction to go.